# Accurately monitoring RAM and swap usage while running zswap compression

Tags: linux, swap, compression, ram, zswap

I'm running zswap on 6.2.0-39-generic (Ubuntu 22.04, HWE).

My understanding is that zswap intercepts pages marked for swap, compresses them (if possible) and stores them in a compressed section of the physical RAM up to a certain, user-specific point. In my case, zswap is set to use a maximum of 25% of the RAM.

However, if I stress my system (which has 256GB of RAM and a 256GB /swapfile):

```
stress --vm-bytes 250G --vm-keep -m 1
```

When viewed through the activity monitor, or free -h etc., firstly my RAM fills and then my "swap" begins to fills - way more than would be necessary to store 250GB.

`free -h` reports:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           251Gi       249Gi       1.9Gi        35Mi       523Mi       598Mi
Swap:          255Gi       128Gi       127Gi
```

However sudo grep -R . /sys/kernel/debug/zswap/ reports:

```
sudo grep -R . /sys/kernel/debug/zswap/
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/same_filled_pages:10982
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/stored_pages:33556168
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/pool_total_size:45804953600
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/duplicate_entry:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/written_back_pages:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/reject_compress_poor:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/reject_kmemcache_fail:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/reject_alloc_fail:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/reject_reclaim_fail:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/pool_limit_hit:0
```

33556168*4096 = ~128GB - which matches swap usage reported by free -h.

So, is the system reporting the uncompressed file size as 'swap' still despite it being compressed by zswap and still on the RAM?

Basically, how can I get an intuitive and reportable sense of:

1. Total physical RAM used (uncompressed)
2. Total physical RAM used (compressed via zswap)
3. Total swap-on-disk used
4. Total swap-on-disk remaining/free to use

Also posted here: https://www.reddit.com/r/kernel/comments/18iykle/accurately_monitoring_ram_and_swap_usage_while/